# How to tell Inertia to rerender view (with updated data) from a webhook?

Tags: laravel, single-page-application, inertiajs

I am using stripe for payments and have a webhook set up for events. - If a customer's credit card expires and he enters new payment info, stripe automatically retries the failed subscription and sends a webhook to show if subscription renewal failed or succeeded.
I like to update the frontend depending on the renewal status which might come in a few seconds after the payment info got updated. - Is there a way to have Inertia re=request the data and re-renders frontend from a webhook - not from a user request?